# Магия маршаллинга с JAXB

Tags: java, java-stream, jaxb

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "graph")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Class1 {

public List<Integer> i1;

public Class1(Integer... i1) {
    if (this.i1 == null) {
        this.i1 = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    for (Integer Int : i1) {
        this.i1.add(Int);
    }
}

public Class1() {
}

@XmlElement
public List<Integer> getI1() {
    return i1;
}

public void setI1(List<Integer> i1) {
    if (this.i1 == null) {
        this.i1 = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    System.out.println("before: " + this.i1);
    this.i1 = i1.stream().map(arg -> arg*2).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("after: " + this.i1);

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Class1{" +
            "i1=" + i1 +
            '}';
}
}
```

Опускаю инициализацию JAXB. Вот какой класс будем маршаллить, а потом анмаршаллить(подробности опускаю): **new Class1(1,2,3)**

результат :

```
before: [ ] 
after: [ ] 
Class1{i1=[ ]}
```

заменяем сеттер на :

```
    public void setI1(List<Integer> i1) {
    if (this.i1 == null) {
        this.i1 = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    System.out.println("before: " + this.i1);
    this.i1 = i1;
    System.out.println("after: " + this.i1);

}
```

результат:

```
before: [ ] 
after: [ ] 
Class1{i1=[1, 2, 3]}
```

Вопрос, что это за адская магия? И можно ли как-то обрабатывать приходящие в сеттер\геттер значения ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вызывается сеттер в него передается пустой список, который создал JAXB. И вы видите это `after: [ ]`. Но потом JAXB начинает заполнять этот список элементами. Но т.к. вы в первом случае создаете новый список, заполненный список просто пропадает где-то в недрах JAXB, во втором же случае вы сохраняете именно ссылку на тот список, который потом будет заполненным и в результате видите `Class1{i1=[1, 2, 3]}`